# How to do ip multicast /broadcast in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, service-discovery, ssdp, multicasting

I have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API service that needs to "publish" a message to the entire local network. So any client application needs to know that there is a Web API service.

What I'm trying to do is notify any client that is installed on any PC on the local network that there exist a Web API that it can connect to. There could be many Web APIs deployed on multiple machines and many clients (also deployed on multiple machines) but they will be on the same network (subnet).

So each client application would receive a message that tells it there is a web service where it can connect to.

I've done this by scanning the subnet for any ip address that respond to a request, but it is to slow.

I can't have a central point so NO RabbitMq or any messaging bus.
I also tried with SSDP using RSSDP library and this works ok when is working, but sometimes it does not.

How to do this?

Comment: _"I also tried with SSDP using RSSDP library and this works ok when is working, but sometimes it does not."_ - SSDP is definitely the best choice here, I strongly suggest you investigate and resolve the occasions when SSDP doesn't work for you instead of trying to reinvent your own lower-level network techniques (besides, broadcast **does not** send messages to "the entire local network" - it only sends packets within the local _broadcast domain_, which is often just 1 or 2 switch hops.

Comment: It seems the *real* question is about service discovery, not network-level broadcasting. Broadcasting won't help here, simply because services may start and publish their presence out of order. Services may not be on the same local network either. The *routers* may easily block broadcast messages too. In SOAP services, service discovery was the job of UDDI which ... didn't catch on. Service brokers and message bus products promised their own versions of service discovery. I suspect that's why you talk about message busses or RabbitMQ, a *message*, not service, broker

Comment: Yes I need to implement service discovery. I mentioned Rabbit Mq and Message bus because it would be easy to implement this if I can use it. But I can't, I cant have a central place to handle this.

Comment: In REST there's no service discovery standard. Before Swagger/OpenAPI there was no service definition standard either. RMQ and message brokers have nothing to do with this BUT they reduce the need for it, as services only need to know about the broker. Broadcast-based solutions like SSDP or UPnP typically only work in a local home network because they're blocked by routers or the managed switches used by corporate data centers. Besides, distributed service discovery doesn't scale very well unless you use complex algorithms and infrastructure

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? You may be able to solve the problem through DNS. At the lowest level, DNS *is* a discovery service. You can create DNS records for each service that point to the actual machines that implement the service. You can register multiple IPs for the same name so clients can fail over to another machine. Clients only need to know the service name, not the actual domain name or IP of the server. The service name could also point to a load balancer or a reverse proxy like YARP that spreads requests among multiple servers

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, The problem I try to solve is this.... I want to create a deployment process for my applications that minimize the user need to know networking infrastructure to use the application. The application itself will be deployed in factories around the world. Those factories all have local network already present but not all of them have internet access. The application is a REST WebService done in asp.net and a MAUI client application that is installed on the machines or mobile devices. I don't want the users of the client to need to know the IP address to connect to the server.

Comment: So my thinking is, I need a way for the MAUI application (client) to find the server it needs to connect and list it in the UI so the user can just select it. So far the SSDP is the best solution as it seems. The problems I have with SSDP are: reporting multiple instances of the same server and not getting the server at all.

Comment: What you describe is the same service discovery problem all distributed applications have for the last 20+ years. `deployed in factories around the world.` in that case you *can't use SSDP at all* without modifying the routers or switches. The problems you mention are exactly the problems inherent in SSDP. With DNS the clients don't have to know the IP, only the domain name. The factory networks have a DNS server (otherwise no machine could talk to each other) which means you can create [an SRV record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record) with a well known name pointing to your service.

Comment: The factory computers will probably be on the same Active Directory domain too, which means you can deploy the server name or configuration using a Group Policy

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Yeah, I can not depend on factory having or not AD.